# Ethernet connectivity issues. My fault or the pi's?

Tags: raspbian, ethernet, connection

I've had ethernet working on my raspberry pi before, but then I switched to using it as a media center and had no need for it. Now I'm switching back and when I plug the cable from my router to the pi, I get no link light and seemingly no connection.

I have difficulties troubleshooting because I've only ever used ssh to talk to the pi (I don't have an hdmi monitor) and I can't do that if it's not connected. Though when I look at my router's attached devices I only see the IP of my desktop and not the pi. Could there be a software issue that is preventing this? Or did the port just go bad? If the latter I assume my best option would be to just buy a new unit rather than attempting repair.

I've tried the basic stuff of checking the ethernet cable and connection. It all checked out fine. I am using a fresh install of Raspbian if that makes a difference.

Any help is appreciated! Let me know if I left any information out

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd plug in the composite port into a TV and see what's happening. Can you plug a keyboard in and see if that works by pressing numlock ?